# Selection + middle mouse click no longer pasting in GitBash

Tags: windows, git-bash, mingw-w64

I have no idea what happened but when I woke up this morning to start working, my selection + middle mouse button no longer pastes the selection.

This has always worked prior to today and the only thing I changed was added a time stamp in my C/Program Files/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh. Unfortunately I did not check if the paste was working prior to this change, but I've since reverted it, thinking it might be the cause.  Still nothing.

[If I enable paste on the right mouse button from the options window, it works.  Still, middle mouse click does nothing even though it is enabled and selected.  See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lplpF.png)

Any idea what may have happened or what I need to change to get the behavior to return?  I can deal with the right click pasting, but muscle memory and working in Linux has me conditioned to use the middle mouse wheel click, so I will begrudgingly.

There are lots of "How to enable selection paste in Git Bash" I've found, but they all point to updating the options like shown in the screenshot and are not one bit helpful. Please do not mark this as a duplicate.

Thank you.